# SQL how to only display the products that have been purchased

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables but can't remember how to do this query.

The 4 tables are products, invoice, productsinvoice and members

I want to display all the products that the user has purchased.

Here is my data for the tables below.

```
products
productID, title, runTime, imageLarge, classification
1, noah, 128 minutes, noahLarge.jpg, M
2, left behind, 105 minutes, leftBehindLarge.jpg, MA 15+
3, green lantern, 133 minutes, greenLantern.jpg, M

invoice
invoiceID, memberID, purchaseDate
1,11,1/10/2014
2,13,15/10/2014


productsinvoice
invoiceID, productID
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 2'

members
memberID, username, pass, first name, last name
11, bob, fwofefef, bob, marley
13, prius, f334ff43f, eski, martey
```

When the user goes to there account page I want to display all the products they have purchased. I can export the sql file from localhost if anybody needs it.

```
$sql = "select P.* 
from products as P 
inner join productsinvoice as PI using (productID)
inner join invoice as I using (invoiceID) 
where I.memberID = ".$_SESSION['user'].">";
```

Brings back You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

$_SESSION['user'] is the memberID

Comment: Do you still remember how to `JOIN` tables?

Comment: Yes I just don't know what to do for the WHERE Ill post what I have already tried

Comment: It's impossible to read code posted in comments.  Move it to your post (*edit*) and format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select P.*
from   products as P
       inner join productsinvoice as PI using (productID)
       inner join invoice as I using (invoiceID)
where  I.memberID = <memberID which may be stored in session when member logs in>
```

I don't see a reason to join the member table, since `memberID` is typically all you need, which is part of the `invoices` table.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Sorry I accidetly forgot to remove the > at the end in the where statement works thank you very much :)